# Scan a PostgreSQL field (of ARRAY type) into a slice of Go structs

Tags: sql, go

Let's say I have:

```
type User struct {
    ID int64 `json:"id"
    Posts []Post `json:"posts"
}

type Post struct {
    ID int64 `json:"id"
    Text string `json:"text"
}
```

The SQL query:

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT u.id AS user_id, p.id AS post_id, p.text AS post_text FROM users u JOIN posts p ON u.id=p.user_id)

SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[post_id::text, post_text]) 
FROM temp
GROUP BY user_id
)
```

What I want is to scan rows from the query above into a slice of User objects:

```
 import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
 )

 var out []User

    rows, _ := client.Query(context.Background(), query) // No error handling for brevity

    for rows.Next() {

        var u User

        if err := rows.Scan(&u.ID, pq.Array(&u.Posts)); err != nil {
            return
        }

        out = append(out, u)

    }
```

Pretty much expectedly, the code above fails with:

`pq: cannot convert ARRAY[4][2] to StringArray`

This makes sense, but is there a way to read the SQL output into my slice of users?

Answer (score 4):

Scanning of multi-dimensional arrays of arbitrary types, like structs, is [not supported](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/26399a/array.go#L427-L430) by `lib/pq`. If you want to scan such an array you'll have to parse and decode it yourself in a custom `sql.Scanner` implementation.

For example:

```golang
type PostList []Post

func (ls *PostList) Scan(src any) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    case []byte:
        data = v
    }

    // The data var holds the multi-dimensional array value,
    // something like: {{"1","foo"}, {"2","bar"}, ...}
    // The above example is easy to parse but too simplistic,
    // the array is likely to be more complex and therefore
    // harder to parse, but not at all impossible if that's
    // what you want.

    return nil
}
```

If you want to learn more about the PostgreSQL array representation syntax, see:

- [Array Input and Output Syntax](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO)

---

An approach that does not require you to implement a parser for PostgreSQL arrays would be to [build](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.9.2.2.5.1.2.1) and pass JSON objects, instead of PostgreSQL arrays, to `array_agg`. The result of that would be a one-dimensional array with `jsonb` as the element type.

```sql
SELECT user_id, array_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', post_id, 'text', post_text)) 
FROM temp
GROUP BY user_id
```

Then the implementation of the custom `sql.Scanner` just needs to delegate to `lib/pq.GenericArray` and another, element-specific `sql.Scanner`, would delegate to `encoding/json`.

```golang
type PostList []Post

func (ls *PostList) Scan(src any) error {
    return pq.GenericArray{ls}.Scan(src)
}

func (p *Post) Scan(src any) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    case []byte:
        data = v
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, p)
}

type User struct {
    ID    int64    `json:"id"`
    Posts PostList `json:"posts"`
}
```